# how do I clear the selection choices with jquery ui autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jquery-ui-1.8.21 autocomplete and having it retrieve data from a DB.  Now I have two quesions - I've searched the web but nothing answers my question - it's retrieving a list of zip codes, but when one is selected from the choices, the list of choices/selections/menu remains on screen.  How do I get the list to clear/disappear when selected by enter key or better by mouse click?

here's my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#container").hide();
            $("#autocomplete").val("");
            $("#autocomplete").focus();
            $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                autoFocus: true,
                source: "search.php",
                minLength: 2, //search after two characters
                //change: function(event, ui) { ... }
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    //do something
                    $("#autocomplete").val(ui.item.autocomplete);
                    $("#container").hide().fadeIn(3000);
                }
            });
        });
```

My next question is - how can I restrict the choices to match only from front to back?  For example, I start typing 55 and get all zip codes beginning with 55, but also any zip codes with 55 like 50055, but I want only those which begin with 55.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: for the second part of the question - all the jQuery autocomplete does is send the entered text to search.php on every keystroke.  You have to take the input in search.php which would be "55" and do a search to you database like SELECT .... LIKE % + 55 + %

Comment: There's a pending edit on this to remove Robert's name. IMHO, that's a stretch for an edit. @user1520692 maybe you'd like to remove Robert, and go into your Profile so your name displays instead of your user #.